# Custom attribute values not appearing in claims after successful login with AWS Cognito in .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have integrated AWS Cognito into my .NET MVC application for user authentication. I extended the user pool schema by adding custom attributes, and I can see these attributes filled in AWS Cognito console for each user.

However, after successfully logging in a user, I am not able to access these custom attribute values in claims. The claims only contain standard attributes like sub, email, and preferred_username, but not the custom attributes.

Here is a summary of what I have done:

Created a user pool in AWS Cognito.
Added custom attributes via the AWS Cognito console (e.g., custom:department).
Configured my .NET MVC application to authenticate users against this user pool using AWS SDK for .NET.
After successful authentication, I retrieve claims using the HttpContext.User.Claims, but custom attributes are missing.